# Error received when running Apex code

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch

i am getting the error

"No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a test method"

whenever I execute the unit test. From my native Apex code it will invoke an apex batch.

Comment: It would be helpful if you pasted your code. I guess that the obvious solution is to split your test code into several methods, and only call 1 executeBatch from each

Comment: Its a common situation with batch apex testing, make sure that See all data is false and as @mkorman mentioned your execute method could only be called once.

Comment: You can try any of the workarounds specified. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176562&language=en_US

Comment: It's almost always when you try to execute the batch with more than 200 records. Share your code if you want better help.

Answer (score 2):

When performing tests and executing batches there are several situations:

1. Start method returns more than 200 records:

**Resolution**: In your start method, check if a test is running and limit the number of records returned. Ensure you are not using SeeAllData = True. In your test limit the number of records you create

```
String query = 'Select Id From Account';
query = test.isRunningTest() == true ? (query + ' Limit 200') : query;
```

2. You are setting the scope size to less than the number of records returned in the start method.

**Resolution** - If setting the scope size - refer to number one or do not set the scope size

3. You are calling `system.executeBatch` in the finish method

**Resolution** One of the few times you should check for `test.isRunningTest()` and not execute the batch in the finish method if a test is running

```
...finish method...
if(!test.isRunningTest()) system.scheduleBatch(New YourBatchClass(),'Example',200,1);
```

**Note** A quick google search on the error message (Always a recommended *first* step) results in:

> Issue : System.UnexpectedException: No more than one executeBatch can
>   be called from within a testmethod.
>
> Causes: Might be we are processing more than 200 records in test class
>   for the batch apex.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176562&language=en_US

Answer (score -2):

You can have one StartTest / StopTest per test method and each test method will be executed independently.

You can have many test methods in any one class.

The **startTest** method marks the point in your test code when your test actually begins. Each test method is allowed to call this method only once. This method does not refresh the context of the test: it adds a context to your test.

Any code that executes after the **stopTest** method is assigned the original limits that were in effect before startTest was called. All asynchronous calls made after the startTest method are collected by the system. When stopTest is executed, all asynchronous processes are run synchronously.

```
Test.StartTest();
....
do your testing for batch here.
This is where you will be running your singular executeBatch()
....
Test.StopTest();
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. We know the OP is using test.startTest() already because of the error and the error is not because the OP has multiple start and stop test